# MSAL Angular - Dynamic Redirect Url Config via document.location.origin not working with AOT

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm writing an Angular Application, while trying my darnest to avoid rebuilding my project based on environment variables. For the basic backend API Calls, it's been pretty easy to work with `document.location.origin` and/or `window.location.origin` respectively. To quote Todd Howard's most infamous line: "It just works". I have to admit, my Applications so far have had rather straightforward and rather simple issues to solve, so I've lacking the knowledge about some more intermediate concepts. However, eventually the client wanted to use the MSAL Library to use it as an alternate Active Directory and for the sake of convenience of a "Single Sign on Strategy". I neglected trying it out in a productive build, realizing that I can't use it like this...

```
 MsalModule.forRoot({
      auth: {
        clientId: '<my_client_id>',
        authority: '',
        redirectUri: window.location.origin,
        postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin + "/login"
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // set to true for IE 11
      },
    },
```

I haven't seen much in terms of applies solutions for a similar case. The only reason I even found out about this particular issue was through this git-issue post

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10957

My question would be, is there a way to provide the window object even for an AOT Build?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, after digging around and given the silence of people... I found a solution by digging through the Git of the MSAL Library.

```
const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE ') > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident/') > -1;


export const protectedResourceMap: [string, string[]][] = [
  ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']]
];

// This setup won't change in our environment, so we were fine with having it statically included
export const clientId = window.location.origin.includes('qa') || window.location.origin.includes('localhost') ? '<qa_id>' : '<prod_id>';

export function MSALConfigFactory(): Configuration {
  return {
    auth: {
      clientId,
      authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/",
      validateAuthority: true,
      redirectUri: window.location.origin,
      postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
      navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: "localStorage",
      storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // set to true for IE 11
    },
  };
}

export function MSALAngularConfigFactory(): MsalAngularConfiguration {
  return {
    popUp: !isIE,
    consentScopes: [
      "user.read",
      "openid",
      "profile"
    ],
    unprotectedResources: [],
    protectedResourceMap,
    extraQueryParameters: {}
  };
}
```

Instead of using the `MsalModule.forRoot({},{})` configuration that doesn't work with a dynamic setup via window, we merely adding the `MsalModule` in the imports object in our `app.module.ts`. So instead of ...

```
imports: [
.. // shortened for terseness
MsalModule.forRoot({},{}),
..
]
```

We do change it to...

```
imports: [
.. // shortened for terseness
MsalModule,
..
]
```

For the providers we're require to provide the `MSAL_CONFIG` class, but we also need to provide what configuration we want to use, something we've done previously. Don't forget to include the MsalService as the application won't run otherwise.

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MSAL_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MSALConfigFactory
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_CONFIG_ANGULAR,
      useFactory: MSALAngularConfigFactory
    },
    MsalService,
  ],
```

This application was tested on a `Angular 7` Project and worked as intended even with a productive build + AOT

Answer (score 0):

You should pass redirectUri and postLogoutRedirectUri as a variables like clientId and authority, 'redirect uri' is also part of the Azure Ad application registration - that should be proper way how to deal with that. You will not be able to test this App in different environments using dynamic values.

Besides that, if your flow is totally non-changeable, maybe use Location service https://angular.io/api/common/Location#path ?